# How to scrape images from a site using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, image-processing, beautifulsoup

i am trying to pull a set of weave sample images from a site

the objective is to create a dataset for creative project

code and screenshot of site to scrape included below

any pointers greatly appreciated, thank you

'''

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import shutil

url = "https://cdndrafts-01-2019.handweaving.net"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
aas = soup.find_all("right-padding", class_='img')

image_info = []
for a in aas:
    image_tag = a.findChildren('img')
    image_info.append((image_tag[0]['src'], image_tag[0]['alt']))

def download_image(image):
    response = requests.get(image[0], stream=True)
    realname = ''.join(e for e in image[1] if e.isalnum())    
    file = open("C://cdnddrafts{}/jpg".format(realname))   
    response.raw.decode_conent = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, file)
    del response

for i in range(0, len(image_info)):
    download_image(image_info[i])
'''
```

[one of the images to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcJqL.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty [in-depth guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-beautifulsoup-edd9441ba734) on how to do this, take a look. Some parts are redundant & you can leave them out.